Number of binary solutions to an underdetermined linear system
I don't know if the answer to the following question is trivial, to me it's not. Suppose that X is an $m\times n$ matrix, with $n>m$, and assume it is a realization from some continuous distribution (e.g. assume that its entries are iid N(0,1)). Consider the equation
$$Xy = t.$$
How many solutions can this equation have if I'm restricting to vectors $y\in \{0,1\}^n$? (assume $t\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is s.t. there's at least one solution, ie at least one vector $y = (y_1,...,y_n)^\top$ with $y_i\in \{0,1\}$ for which $Xy=t$). Because $n>m$ the columns of $X$ are necessarily linearly dependent, but since only binary vectors are considered, I wonder if it may still be the case that the solution is unique; are there counter-examples?

sorry, I corrected $p$ to $m$. Thanks!

I'd say that the probability that there exists a set of columns that sum up to $t$ equals 0. However, you have placed some conditions on $t$, but I don't think these change much.

Thank you @Matteo! That sounds exactly right. There were no restrictions on t except it’s in the range (or that at least one solution to the system exists)
